# PHP: outsync or concurrent session variable arrays inside session

Tags: php, session, variables

I'm having a really wierd problem with PHP session variables. Based on the session ID it looks like there would be double variables inside same session which naturally cannot be possible.

The problem is that 'quote' session variable should remain same when form in page is submitted which reloads the page itself. The $_SESSION['quote'] variable is set only if it's not defined, what happens in first two reloads as can be seen logs below.

Debug code:

```
echo "\n Current session id: ".session_id();
    echo "\n _SESSION['quote']: ".$_SESSION['quote'];
    $_SESSION['counter'] = isset($_SESSION['counter'])? $_SESSION['counter'] +1 : 0;
    echo "\n _SESSION['counter']: ".$_SESSION['counter'];

Output when page is reloaded(form submitted):

 Current session id: r5i15u4s9e20ud4j6jke8ln376; 
 $_SESSION['quote']: ; 
 $_SESSION['counter']: 0; 
 set  _SESSION['quote']: 984; 

 Current session id: r5i15u4s9e20ud4j6jke8ln376; 
 $_SESSION['quote']: ; 
 $_SESSION['counter']: 0; 
 set  _SESSION['quote']: 985; 

 Current session id: r5i15u4s9e20ud4j6jke8ln376; 
 $_SESSION['quote']: 985; 
 $_SESSION['counter']: 1; 

 Current session id: r5i15u4s9e20ud4j6jke8ln376; 
 $_SESSION['quote']: 985; 
 $_SESSION['counter']: 2; 

 Current session id: r5i15u4s9e20ud4j6jke8ln376; 
 $_SESSION['quote']: 984; 
 $_SESSION['counter']: 1; 

 Current session id: r5i15u4s9e20ud4j6jke8ln376; 
 $_SESSION['quote']: 985; 
 $_SESSION['counter']: 3; 

 Current session id: r5i15u4s9e20ud4j6jke8ln376; 
 $_SESSION['quote']: 984; 
 $_SESSION['counter']: 2;
```

This problem happens with Firefox and IE.
Any advice or tip would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

---EDIT---
Added echo serialize($_SESSION); as proposed.

```
<?php session_start();
echo "\nSerialized data at begin of page: ";
echo serialize($_SESSION);

echo "\n Current session id: ".session_id();
echo "\n _SESSION['quote']: ".$_SESSION['quote'];
$_SESSION['counter'] = isset($_SESSION['counter'])? $_SESSION['counter'] +1 : 0;
echo "\n _SESSION['counter']: ".$_SESSION['counter'];
```

OUTPUT:

```
Initial loading of page:
  Serialized data at begin of page: a:0:{}
  Current session id: vbbpohof2jo757eaj5jrp4dv02
  $_SESSION['quote']: 
  $_SESSION['counter']: 0
  ...
  Serialized data at end of page: a:1:{s:7:"counter";i:0;}


Page 1. reload by form submit:
  Serialized data at begin of page: a:0:{}
  Current session id: vbbpohof2jo757eaj5jrp4dv02
  $_SESSION['quote']: 
  $_SESSION['counter']: 0
  ...
  Serialized data at end of page: a:3:{s:7:"counter";i:0;s:8:"quote";i:1023;s:9:"quotedate";s:10:"2010-11-18";}


Page 2. reload by form submit:
  Serialized data at begin of page: a:1:{s:7:"counter";i:0;}
  Current session id: vbbpohof2jo757eaj5jrp4dv02
  $_SESSION['quote']: 
  $_SESSION['counter']: 1
  ...
  Serialized data at end of page: a:3:{s:7:"counter";i:1;s:8:"quote";i:1024;s:9:"quotedate";s:10:"2010-11-18";}


Page 3. reload by form submit:
  Serialized data at begin of page: a:3:{s:7:"counter";i:0;s:8:"quote";i:1023;s:9:"quotedate";s:10:"2010-11-18";}
  Current session id: vbbpohof2jo757eaj5jrp4dv02
  $_SESSION['quote']: 1023
  $_SESSION['counter']: 1
  ...
  Serialized data at end of page: a:3:{s:7:"counter";i:1;s:8:"quote";i:1023;s:9:"quotedate";s:10:"2010-11-18";}

Page 4. reload by form submit:
  Serialized data at begin of page: a:3:{s:7:"counter";i:1;s:8:"quote";i:1024;s:9:"quotedate";s:10:"2010-11-18";}
  Current session id: vbbpohof2jo757eaj5jrp4dv02
  $_SESSION['quote']: 1024
  $_SESSION['counter']: 2
  ...
  Serialized data at end of page: a:3:{s:7:"counter";i:2;s:8:"quote";i:1024;s:9:"quotedate";s:10:"2010-11-18";}

Page 5. reload by form submit:
  Serialized data at begin of page: a:3:{s:7:"counter";i:1;s:8:"quote";i:1023;s:9:"quotedate";s:10:"2010-11-18";}
  Current session id: vbbpohof2jo757eaj5jrp4dv02
  $_SESSION['quote']: 1023
  $_SESSION['counter']: 2
  ...
  Serialized data at end of page: a:3:{s:7:"counter";i:2;s:8:"quote";i:1023;s:9:"quotedate";s:10:"2010-11-18";}
```

I hope this demonstrates my problem better than unclear original description. Sorry for that. This time "two concurrent" session variable arrays, if such can be, seem to be active one after another. Sometimes other is active few times and then another...

---EDIT---

Comment: This is confussing. Provide more details. The output does not seem to be one that should be received from your debug code. Double check it.

Comment: Yeah, and where does `quote` come from? Why does it get increased?

Comment: Output is exactly what comes out, only the ';' added by me as without that everything went to one line in my post and 'set  _SESSION' logging was not included as it's latter in the page. It's not relavant, the log demonstrates the problem well. @Pekka: 'quote' is set if $_SESSION['quote'] is not set and it is suppose to be increment in that case. The problem is that it should not be get incremented as it's already set on this session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created simple script to simulate the problem where I dump session variables in the begin and the end of page. Page is having single button which will refresh the page and in the begin of page is counter which is stored into session variables. Finding was that if pressing button quickly everything works well but if waiting >10s then session variables are empty (counter variable) and after that when pressing the button either original counter or concurrent session variable array counter is incremented.

I also isolated the problem into the server where original problematic website is hosted. Problem cannot be reproduce in localhost nor other server which I tested. So the conclusion is that some configuration in server is wrong or there is a bug in PHP 5.2.9 or some other component.

Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

All wierd, where does "set _SESSION" come from?
does the script act on both post and get?

make sure it reaches session_start() on both methods.

Comment: "set_SESSION" log was not included in my description and it's executed in case the $_SESSION['quote'] is not set which is the initial case. The wierd thing is that it gets executed twice and as you can see from the 'counter' everything seems to be set twice but having different values. Yes, script is having both 'POST' and 'GET' functionality, although neither related to 'quote' session variable. 'session_start()' is the first line on the source file.

Comment: Please do not focus on too much is the log matching to provided code or what is 'quote' if you feel that those are confusing or something would be missing. Instead can you explain how the 'counter' variable can have such values in same session? It's not used or modified anywhere else than in provided code...

Comment: It's hard to track down the bug(?), and the discrepancy between the log and code makes it even harder. However, I'd suggest you put >> echo serialize($_SESSION) at top and end of your script to follow the exec better. Caps error? View Source? (chrome reloads page..)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion to serialize array, it points out my problem more clearly. Please see logs in above description section. Sorry but I don't follow what you mean with "Caps error".

Comment: Now I'm facing random problems also with shopping cart and captcha validation. I created simple isolated test code for captcha case and debug finding was that it fails randomly and then session variable array is contaning previous captcha inputted by user. Any of these problems doesn't happen on localhost only on real server. There must be some configuration problem or something breaking down. Any ideas what could be checked from server side?

Answer (score 0):

Laowai, glad to help,

First, your code has errors:

```
isset($_SESSION['counter']) ? $_SESSION['counter'] +1 : 0;
```

should be

```
isset($_SESSION['counter']) ? $_SESSION['counter']++ : $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
```

Secondly, if you still have production-server-errors, check access-log to track down any unintended requests (from jQuery or whatever) messing up your controller(?)-requests.

Third, I'd suggest you read your $_SESSION data ONCE at top and copy to regular $var, and at end of script, write back to $_SESSION. $_SESSION are most often files, and strange things may happen on servers with high load.

```
$sesscopy = $_SESSION;
//do everything...
//now done...
$_SESSION = $sesscopy;
```

regards,
/t eriksson